# If $f:\mathrm R\to\mathrm R, f(x)=\sqrt3\sin x-\cos x+px-q,$ and $f^{-1}$ exists, find $p$ and $q$.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, trigonometry, solution-verification

> If $f:\mathrm R\to\mathrm R, f(x)=\sqrt3\sin x-\cos x+px-q,$ and $f^{-1}$ exists, find $p$ and $q$.

**My Attempt:**

If $f^{-1}$ exists, that means $f$ is one-one and onto.

For $f$ to be onto, $p\ne0$.

For $f$ to be one-one, $f'$ should be either always positive or always negative.

$f'(x)=\sqrt3\cos x+\sin x+p$

Thus, $f'$ varies from $p-2$ to $p+2$.

For $f'$ to be always positive, smaller value should be positive i.e. $p\gt2$.

For $f'$ to be always negative, larger value should be negative i.e. $p\lt-2$.

Thus, my final answer is $p\in(-\infty,-2)\cup(2,\infty)$ and $q\in\mathrm R$

Is this correct?

Also, $-2$ and $2$ may also be considered as that would make the derivative zero only once.

Comment: When $p=2$ (or $-2$) the derivative won't be $0$ only once. For example, it's $0$ at $x = -5 \pi/6$ and at $x=7 \pi /6$.

Comment: @jjagmath yes, thanks

Comment: $\sqrt{3}\cos x+\sin x=2\sin(\pi/3+x)$

Comment: @BobDobbs sorry, I didn't get your point.

Comment: You are overthinker.

Answer (score 1):

Thus $f$ varies from $p-2$ to $p+2$... Why?

We need to complete angles in one function: $f'(x)=\sqrt{3}\cos x+\sin x+p=2\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos x+\frac{1}{2}\sin x\right)+p=2\left(\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})\cos x+\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})\sin x\right)+p.$
Thus,
$f'(x)=2\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}+x)+p.$ So, $p-2\leq f'(x)\leq p+2$ as you said. To make $f'(x)$ bijective, we have two strategy: Either, $f'(x)$ will be non-negative in which case we have to choose $p\geq 2$ or $f'(x)$ will be non-positive in which case we have to choose $p\leq -2$. We conclude that, if $p\in (-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)$, the function $f(x)$ is 1-1 and thus bijective. Note that surjectivity is clear. Yes, there is no condition on $q$: $q\in\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

$2$ and $-2$ should be included. Just consider the graph of $f(x)=x+\sin x$, $\,f$ is a bijection and strictly increasing.